# react-google-maps "google is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-google-maps

I'm using the **react-google-maps** in one of my react projects. But I'm getting this error:

```
google is not defined
```

I've tried several other solutions from *stack-overflow* but none worked for me.
Here's my code:

```
/* global google */
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow, HeatmapLayer, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { markerPosition } from "./MapData";
... // other code

const ExampleTraffic = (props) => {

 ... // other code

  return (
    <LoadScript
      id="script-loader"
      googleMapsApiKey="My Api Key"
      region="BD"
      libraries={libraries}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        id='example-map'
        mapContainerStyle={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
        zoom={13}
        center={{
          lat: 23.684994,
          lng: 90.356331
        }}
        clickableIcons={true}
      >
        ... // other code

        <HeatmapLayer data={[
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.862257, 22.862257),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.853746, 89.534611),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.847735, 89.537359),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.845773, 89.551920),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.861434, 89.534056),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.864945, 89.514299),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.868741, 89.527406),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.866369, 89.528873),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.857052, 89.547997),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.845172, 89.530171),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.854094, 89.562946),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.868963, 89.507291),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.871177, 89.547143),
                new google.maps.LatLng(22.897430, 89.513818)
         ]}
         />
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript >
  );
}

export default ExampleTraffic;
```

What's wrong with my code? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to use ```window.google``` you have to add a script tag of google api in the ```index.html``` in public folder.
But in case you have already defined the google api in ```LoadScript```.
If you would tell me, exactly what you want to do, I may help you with using google

Comment: use 
```{lat: 37.782, lng: -122.447, weight: 0.5},
        {lat: 37.782, lng: -122.443, weight: 2},
        {lat: 37.782, lng: -122.441, weight: 3},
        {lat: 37.782, lng: -122.439, weight: 2},
        {lat: 37.782, lng: -122.435, weight: 0.5},
        {lat: 37.785, lng: -122.447, weight: 3},
        {lat: 37.785, lng: -122.445, weight: 2},
        {lat: 37.785, lng: -122.441, weight: 0.5},
        {lat: 37.785, lng: -122.437, weight: 2},
        {lat: 37.785, lng: -122.435, weight: 3}```

formate as the props in data of ```<HeatmapLayer>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using

```
new window.google.maps.LatLng(22.862257, 22.862257),
new window.google.maps.LatLng(22.853746, 89.534611),
```

Instead of

```
new google.maps.LatLng(22.862257, 22.862257),
new google.maps.LatLng(22.853746, 89.534611),
```